# What is a wil::ResultException and what does it mean to rethrow?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, microsoft-ui-automation

Using UI Automation for some Windows I get the following exceptions on a `IUIAutomationElement::FindAll()` call using VS2017.  First question, what is a `wil:ResultException` and what does it mean it `rethrow at memory address 0`?  I check the `FindAll()` result and doesn't seem to have `FAILED(hr)` because it outputs a debug message if it did and it's not.

Exception thrown at 0x00007FF897AC3E49 in app.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: wil::ResultException at memory location 0x000000550AF2BDC0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF897AC3E49 in app.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything, you merely found out that Microsoft programmers eat their own [dog food](https://github.com/microsoft/wil/wiki/Error-handling-helpers).  The chatty tracing can often be helpful to diagnose UWP failures, UI Automation can easily trigger it by accident.

Comment: [Exception based error handling](https://github.com/microsoft/wil/wiki/Error-handling-helpers#exception-based-error-handling) explains what `wil::ResultException` is. You can rethrow an exception from inside a `catch` clause using `throw;`, or by calling `rethrow_exception` with a previously captured `exception_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is related or not. I turned on the fairly new "Use Text cursor indicator" as users are telling us our app can crash when it is on. After doing some testing, I was closing the app and got an access violation deep in UIAutomation.dll. The system was just exiting the process. I was trying to duplicate the crash and though I didn't crash, I just saw this same message and the reply to this post that mentioned UIAutomation. The "fairly" new setting is new to me because our IT just allowed the version update that has the setting on our boxes.

The crash occurred while doing a PeekMessage during the exit of the process. We had a static c++ object that was being deleted and during that call, it called the API. I rearranged the code to make the call that used PeekMessage so it happened before the process exited. That avoided that crash. However, we are MFC based and in a debug build, if any code does an ASSERT during shutdown, MFC's assert code does a PeekMessage to remove WM_QUIT before showing the assert message box. So, we can still crash there randomly in our debug builds.

When running with the Text Cursor Indicator on, I see a lot of these "wil" exceptions in the debug output window (release or debug builds). Many seem to occur when a window that has the indicator drawn over it closes. Example - standard file open dialog. I open it, click the path edit box and when I close the dialog, I get some of those exceptions. Turning off the indicator setting avoids all of that and the crashes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).